# How much time should the mouse left button be held?

Tags: python, security, artificial-intelligence

If you want to detect a Bot that is clicking on a button when he has to, could you look how long the left button stays down before being up again?
I mean a script like this one (python):

```
import win32api, win32con

win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)
```

Will click really fast. Probably faster than a human. And always at (really closely) the same speed. Could an anti-bot system detect that?

So you can add a `time.sleep(float)` instruction between the two mouse_event's. But should it be randomised? We probably have a slight difference of time between two clicks, less precise than a computed click.

So how much time should we make the sleep last (min and max of the randrange)?

It's probably too much effort for being undetected but is that possible?

So quick recap:

- Can we detect a bot on the click speed and click time never changing even a bit?
- How long does an average person press the button down before letting it go up? If I want to stay undetected should I randomise this time, and with which min and max?

(I'm not talking about other existing security like checking if you press the same pixel over and over.)

Comment: If a bot [author] becomes aware of you checking its mouse movement speed, there's a very simple workaround for that: it can start moving the cursor slowly across the screen, including random jumps and varying speed, to imitate movements of a real human.

Comment: Here it's not about mouse movement but about the click speed.
But how can the bot be aware that I'm checking the movement?

Comment: It should be obvious that the same thing applies there.

Comment: Ok, and do you know what is the human click speed?

Comment: Nope. I'd think this is also complicated by different input methods, which may report click speeds differently. For instance, touch screens/track pads will have very different speeds than mouse buttons, and disabled users using voice-over or other assistive technologies to move the mouse around may appear "bot like" in their interaction.

Comment: Sounds like a conversation between bots who can't find a human to measure his clicking speed. :)

Comment: Well actually it's what I decided to do once back from work. My question was about the necessity of such a thing. So I asked the time aswell. I'll add my code and time found once it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, bots can and are detected this way.

Yes, adding a random offset to the click speed, delay, mouse path, movement speed, and many more things is the standard solution to circumvent this kind of detection. There are many other ways to detect bots though.

To get an average click speed, write a short program that logs the timestamps for mouseDown and mouseUp events and click in it.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but anyway, according to this paper here [Transfer learning for behavioral biometrics](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9851764)

It shows that
the average mouse click lasts 85ms, with Q3 = 95ms, Q1= 75ms; with an upper fence of 135ms and a lower fence of 55ms.

Then you can turn this distribution into a gaussian for easy implementation.
To implement this in your code(approximately) in python, you can use NumPy normal distribution, with mean 85ms, and to calculate the standard deviation you can use the rule of thumb:

```
sd = IQR/1.35
```

And therefore, sd = 14.8148148, u=85ms